# Unable to do any action on a specific AWS S3 file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For some reasons, I am unable to perform any actions against a specific S3 Bucket file.

The Bucket policy is as follow:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::[AWS_ACCOUNT_ID]:root"]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:DeleteObject*",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket_name]",
                "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket_name]/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I check the owner of the specific file (`index.yaml`), I can see it is the same as the other files on which I can perform actions :

```
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "index.yaml",
            "LastModified": "2017-04-06T18:01:55.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"xxxxxxx\"",
            "Size": 50,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "ID": "1111111111"
            }
        },
        {
            "Key": "conf.tgz",
            "LastModified": "2016-05-06T04:12:36.000Z",
            "ETag": "\"yyyyyyyyyy\"",
            "Size": 60,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            "Owner": {
                "ID": "1111111111"
            }
        }
}
```

Some more informations:

- I have admin rights ;
- I can't copy the files from the bucket to the bucket (`aws s3 cp s3://[bucket_name]/index.yaml s3://[bucket_name]/index_copied.yaml`) ;
- I can't copy the file locally (`aws s3 cp s3://[bucket_name]/index.yaml index.yaml`) ;
- For every other files, I can perform theses actions.

In any case, the error I got from AWS is the following:

> fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

At this point, I am pretty stuck. 
I tried to open the Bucket with `Action: [s3:*]` but it did not work either.

I have the feeling that there is something wrong woth the file owner/permission.

What do I miss?

**Edit:** 
The issue has eventually been fixed by emptying the Bucket and recreating it. I believe there is a bug on Amazon's side but can't tell much as I still don't understand what was wrong.

Comment: Did you try perform some actions on object using UI (AWS Console)? Or only using commands?

Comment: Both, neither worked. With UI, I only get `Access Denied`.

Comment: Are you actually the `root` user or just an IAM user with administrator privileges? (They are different) If you want to test the theory, make the principal `arn:aws:iam::[AWS_ACCOUNT_ID]:*`

Comment: *"I believe there is a bug on Amazon's side"*... that's possible, but unlikely.  You didn't mention who the owner of the object was, in the bucket listing, and whether that is the same account that owns the bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I also think it is very unlikely. I am the owner of the Bucket, and it resides in the same account as the one who owns the Bucket. 
TomNijs:  It may have been indeed the solution, but can't test it anymore since the problem is solved.